# Resolving a Function Call in an Existential Type

Tags: haskell, types, existential-type

Upon reading [this page](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Existentially_quantified_types) on existentials in Haskell, I was compelled to test the limits of this behavior, so I wrote the following code snippet:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}

data Showable = forall a. Show a => MkShowable a

pack :: Show a => a -> Showable
pack = MkShowable

instance Show Showable where
    show (MkShowable x) = show x
```

The `Showable` type is very similar to the `ShowBox` type created in the aforementioned link. Then I created this contrived example to illustrate my question.

```
showSomething :: Bool -> Showable
showSomething True = pack 1
showSomething False = pack "ABC"

main :: IO ()
main = do
  x <- getLine
  let y = read x
  print $ showSomething y
```

This code (which works fine) asks the user for input (which should be 'True' or 'False'), and then prints out `1` if it is True or `"ABC"` if it is False.

But I'm failing to fully understand how the system does this. Mathematically, it makes perfect sense. But I don't see how the computer is able to resolve it. To me, it looks like the system makes a decision at runtime concerning whether to call `Int`'s `show` instance or `String`'s `show` function, but that would imply the existence of a something like C++'s vtables, which I don't believe Haskell has a concept of.

My question is: how does it resolve that? The system can't know in advance whether I'm going to input true or false, so it can't know which `show` to call at compile-time, yet it clearly works in both cases.

Comment: Yup, typeclasses are transformed into additional dictionary-like argument, which contains method implementations for concrete instance. This argument is passed around in every function with `Showable =>` signature.

Comment: Here's an amazing video, SPJ talking about it: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6COvD8oynmI

Comment: GHC has something _exactly like_ C++ vtables. (Although we generally call them "method dictionaries".)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way how to implement type classes is passing a dictionary of functions that implement a type class under the hood. For example a function with signature

```
f :: Show a => T
```

would be translated into

```
f' :: (a -> String) -> T
```

by the compiler and whenever `show` is used inside `f`, it's replaced by the additional argument (in reality there would be more functions, all that are declared in `Show`).

Similarly the data type

```
forall a . Show a => MkShowable a
```

would be translated into

```
forall a . MkShowable' (a -> String) a
```

So the transformed code might look like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}

data Showable' = forall a . MkShowable' (a -> String) a

pack' :: Show a => a -> Showable'
pack' = MkShowable' show

instance Show Showable' where
    show (MkShowable' f x) = f x

showSomething :: Bool -> Showable'
showSomething True = pack' 1
showSomething False = pack' "ABC"
```

When `pack` is called, the `show` implementation is passed to the constructor as well so that it's available when needed.

Answer (score 2):

Yep. A bunch of language features (most of them extensions) in Haskell can be viewed as basically implementing many of the concepts that are bundled up in the complex monolith of a "class" in OO-programming, but *individually* as separate features. Existential types with type class constraints basically *are* vtables!

In order for `show (MkShowable x)` to work without any other constraints, `MkShowable x` has to contain enough information to know how to `show x`. So that's exactly what it does; even though it only has one field, it actually contains additional information.

This is essentially the same as how a function `foo :: Show a => a; foo x = show x` seems to only have one parameter, but actually has to receive enough additional information to know how `show x`; it can't be "hard-wired" in because `foo` is likely used at several different types. But where `foo` requires its caller to pass that information in from the outside (and the type system enforces this), a `Showable` value **contains** exactly the same information, in order to be able to extract it for passing to functions like `foo`.

So now with this facility, unlike without `ExistentialQuantification` the problem of knowing which `show` instance to call is just selecting between two values of the same type (which contains a `Show` instance for some unknown type together with a value of that same type), which is easy to do; no compile-time knowledge of which one it is is needed.

Comment: Unfortunately, no compile-time knowledge of which one it is is *used*, even if it is available. I filed a bug report about this, but unfortunately it looks like it would take a fairly significant amount of restructuring to fix.